# Closure not working in Filter method

Tags: scala, collections, apache-spark

I have written the following under the impression that `line` is some sort of keyword when iterating & filtering through multiple lines of text. However I get error upon compilation. I am aware that the `line` word in the `Spark` code is used under some other context which is why my code is not working. I have started learning Scala for 2 days now. So please be patient with my little understanding of the syntax & slangs.

Can somebody explain why `line` works in Spark code & not in plain scala code? Also can it be something other then `line` in spark & simple scala code.

**Plain Scala Code:**

```
val myString = """Hello world line 1
      line 2
      Line 3""";

 println(myString.filter(line => line.contains(3)));
                                   ^^^^^^ error here
```

**Spark Code:**

val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val logData = sc.textFile(logFile, 2).cache()
val numAs = logData.filter(line => line.contains("a")).count()

Comment: When you get an error, don't just say "there is an error". Include the actual error message - it contains a lot of information about what might be wrong. So, what is the error message that you get? `line` is not a keyword or reserved word in Scala.

Answer (score 3):

`line` is just the name of a variable you are binding, it's no way special neither in plain Scala nor in Spark.

I don't know much of Spark but I believe that the `logData.filter` function is a a function that iterates over lines of a multi-line string and filters them by some predicate on the line; `logData` in this case is not a String but some Spark-provided class.

When you instead use the Scala's `filter` function provided for `String` you are iterating over characters, so the `line` variable you are binding is of type `Char`, which doesn't have a `contains` function.

If you want to iterate over lines of a plain Scala string you can do something like:

```
yourString.split("\n").filter(line => line.contains('3'))
```

The `split` bit makes an `Array[String]` containing the lines and then you can filter the array; in that case line is of type `String` and the type of `'3'` has to be `Char` for this to work as expected.